# Вывод содержимого в шаблоне по условию

Tags: angular

Можно ли упростить эту запись, оставить один блок и выводить содержимое блока по тернарному оператору?

```html
<div *ngIf="condition">
    Привет
</div>
<div *ngIf="!condition">
    Пока
</div>
```

Comment: а зачем тебе это? > duplication is cheaper than the wrong abstraction @ Sandi Metz

Comment: если посмотришь на ответ ниже, то убедишься, что кол-во кода 1 в 1 одинаковое 

Comment: Когда содержимое простое, то можно и  `{{ !!condition ? 'Привет' : 'Пока' }}` забубенить

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006589/1597497) из англоязычного StackOverflow, можно так:

```
<div *ngIf="condition;else other_content">
    Привет
</div>
<ng-template #other_content>Пока</ng-template>
```